# Does this sentence make any sense to you?

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis

"Never play the podcast from anywhere but the start"

What does this sentence mean to you? By podcast I mean a house music episode that is one hour long.

Comment: It has two negatives so is hard to figure out. But it means "start at the beginning, not somewhere in the middle".

Comment: Have you written this or read this?  I would take this to mean don't ever start listening from a point, say, 10 minutes in, always start listening from the beginning of the podcast.  However, knowing what I know about podcasts, I think using **never** here is absurd, I don't think I'll suffer any ill effects if I happen to want to jump to 20:03.  Maybe if the admonition was, "For the full effect, always start listening from the beginning of the podcast" it'd at least be put in some sort of context.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes sense. Whether it is identical to the sense you have in mind is a different question entirely. For starters, I would not take *podcast* to mean "a house music episode that is one hour long". But since the sentence will be found in some sort of context, this is probably not an issue.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I don't have 15 reputation points, otherwise I would've voted you up. :)

Answer (score 0):

> What does this sentence mean to you?

Start listening to the series at episode 1.

With many podcasts, you could just start at a random episode and as long as you started at the beginning of the episode (why on earth would you do otherwise, anyway?) you'll be able to get what's going on.

Some though build on what has gone before, especially if they are fiction. While you certainly could start listening to [Welcome to Night Vale](http://commonplacebooks.com/) at a later episode, there are some that would make little sense on their own, and I'd definitely recommend you should start with the very first. If someone said of another pod cast ""Never play [it] from anywhere but the start", I'd assume they meant this was similar in that regard.

> By podcast I mean a house music episode that is one hour long.

Why?

I don't think you could reasonably expect people to understand you meant house music, hour long, or indeed episode (rather than series, though as with other serial publications you do get the word applied *also* to individual episodes).

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, but it comes off as what Steven Pinker calls a "garden path sentence." The sentence could read that the podcast is being played from the location of the listener. That it's not comes as a surprise to the reader. 
This information is from The Language Instinct: How the Mind Creates Language, published 1994 by William Morrow and Company, Inc.